# Setting up a chain of Jenkins jobs all pointing to a single repository and triggered by Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I am trying to improve my Jenkins setup to make it more maintainable and powerful. I have a set of dependent libraries. When one developer commits, I would like to immediately run the unit tests on that library and the downstream libraries.

The builds are all configured to be triggered by Jenkins, but monitor different subfolders of the repository (one job jobA monitors /srcA/ , another jobB monitors /srcB/ etc)

Each job compiles the library (c++), runs unit-tests and publishes coverage results.
What I do now is simply manage each job on this particular project independently.

I would like to setup a chain, ideally with something which produces some graphical overview of what has happened.

Let's say my job chain is as follow:

```
 loggingLib
    |
    V
 guiLib
    |
    V
 commonLib
   / \
  /   \
libA  libB
  \   /
   \ /
    |
    V
  libFunction
```

I would like a commit to loggingLib to trigger all the downstream builds and tests, so that I guarantee that an upstream change won't break the downstream libs. But there are some major commits which affect multiple libraries (bumping revision numbers, API changes, etc). The commit will (gerrit-) trigger all impacted libs (for example, guiLib and commonLib). In that case, the guiLib will chain-trigger commonLib. I would like to find a way that if guiLib is triggered, then commonLib is not triggered independently, but only as a child of guiLib. Also, if a child build fails, the parent build should be marked as failing as well, since it is the cause for the problem.

As you may see above, there is also a diamond shape, so libA and libB must trigger libFunction when they are complete if they are the "root" of the trigger, but commonLib must trigger both libA and libB (typical use for the Join plugin or buildflow).

Using combinations of various plugins (parameterized, join, conditionalBuildStep), I can more or less get what I want, but it is hardly maintainable and I cannot avoid a commit affecting multiple folders to generate multiple builds for that folder (direct + as a dependency).

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: in Gerrit trigger Version 2.11.0-beta-1 jobs can be triggered with topic. Maybe you can use it.